# Making mongo's aggregation pipeline case insenstive

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework

I am using mongo's aggregation pipeline to do a search on a collection.

Here is my filter condition:

```
filter := bson.D{
        {"$project", bson.D{
            {"names", bson.D{
                {"$filter", bson.D{
                    {"input", "$names"},
                    {"as", "names"},
                    {"cond", bson.D{
                        {"$and", bson.A{
                            bson.D{{"$eq", bson.A{"$$names.firstname", "John"}}},
                            bson.D{{"$eq", bson.A{"$$names.lastname", "Doe"}}},
                        }},
                    }},
                }},
            }},
        }},
    }
```

This filter works well but it is case sensitive. If pass `john` instead of `John`, it returns 0 documents. How do I make `firstname` and `lastname` case insenstive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$regexMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/) into `$filter` like this:

Note that I've used Regex `^name$` to match only the word, you can use the regex you want, but with option `i`, the regex is case insensitive.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "names": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$names",
          "as": "names",
          "cond": {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$regexMatch": {
                  "input": "$$names.firstname",
                  "regex": "^John$",
                  "options": "i"
                }
              },
              {
                "$regexMatch": {
                  "input": "$$names.lastname",
                  "regex": "^Doe$",
                  "options": "i"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PcA2ST82xLq)